# Owl slider scrolling off page when last slide is mousover'd

Tags: jquery, slider, overflow, graphic, owl-carousel

I am having some difficulties figuring out why this is happening. I am using owl graphic slide and when the mouse hovers over the last slide element the page wants to scroll off the page to the right!?!! At one point I thought I had narrowed it down to a padding issue created by owls translate3d css but have not been able to find that again. I've tried shrinking the containers to confirm a padding problem in the css but I still get the same problem. Shutting off other jquery, and checking console for problems has  still left me scratching my head. I have opened the website for a preview so you all can see what is happening. http://cypion.com/template.php. use the slider and go to the last slide and touch it with the mouse. Any ideas?

EDIT Chrome seems to be the only browser with this issue.

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag descriptions when you're adding them to your question.  [tag:owl] is for "The Web Ontology Language (OWL) is a vocabulary for creating schemas (ontologies), i.e. definitions of classes, properties and the relationships between them."  You want [tag:owl-carousel].  I've edited the tags this time.

Answer (score 0):

I more or less stumbled onto the problem. When I had discovered that the chrome browser was the only one having a problem I began disabling extensions. Pinit extension was causing the problem and when disabled all is well. I still dont know why this caused a problem to begin with.